# Merge Row based on Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have df like this

```
   Date    Description  Debit     Credit     Balance originalIdx
0   01-03-19    AAAA        NaN        NaN        49Cr       0
1   01-03-19    ASSS        NaN      6,000.00     55Cr       1
2   NaN         XYZ         ABC        saa        NaN        1
3   01-03-19    ABZ        289.00      NaN        55Cr       3
```

I want this

```
      Date     Description       Debit        Credit     Balance  originalIdx
0   01-03-19    AAAA              NaN          NaN        49Cr        0
1   01-03-19    ASSSXYZABCsaa     NaN        6,000.00     55Cr        1
3   01-03-19    ABZ              289.00         NaN       55Cr        3
```

I want to merge The Row if The originalIdx Is the same , so merge the Row in Description Column

this was my real time data
[image]

Comment: Just write a for loop?

Comment: yes .you can try

Comment: @kabooya, please don't suggest for loop when dealing with pandas

Comment: @JoeFerndz can you plz help me?

Comment: should it merge dates as well if dates are different? Or are you trying to merge only description column

Comment: No.. If dates is different then value also have different so we can't merge it

Comment: What if the value was `2  01-04-19     XYZ    ABC   saa    56Cr    1`? Can this be a valid scenario?

Comment: No this this was not valid

Comment: I upload the my real time data image check this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229803/discussion-between-user14784453-and-joe-ferndz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Date` will have `NaN` if the row needs to be merged, here's the code.

first create a dummy column `merged`. It will merge all the values of `Description`, `Debit`, and `Credit`. It will only merge if the value is alpha (excludes numeric values)

Then replace `Description` by using groupby transform (lambda) function.

Then dropna if rows have `Date` as NaN. Also drop the temp column `merged`.

```
df['merged'] = df[['Description','Debit','Credit']].apply(lambda x: ''.join([str(a) for a in x if pd.notnull(a) and not isinstance(a, float)]) ,axis=1)

df['Description'] = df.groupby("originalIdx")['merged'].transform(lambda x: "".join(x))
df.dropna(subset=['Date'],inplace=True)
df.drop(columns='merged',inplace=True)
print (df)
```

This will give you:

```
       Date    Description  Debit  Credit Balance  originalIdx
0  01-03-19           AAAA    NaN     NaN    49Cr            0
1  01-03-19  ASSSXYZABCsaa    NaN  6000.0    55Cr            1
3  01-03-19            ABZ  289.0     NaN    55Cr            3
```

Here's the full code with data and output.

Replace your `df['merged']` with the below code:

```
df['merged'] = df[['Description','Debit','Credit']].apply(lambda x: ''.join([str(a) for a in x if pd.notnull(a) and not isinstance(a, float)]) ,axis=1)
```

Full Code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 200)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 250)
c = ['Date','Description','Debit','Credit','Balance','originalIdx']
d = [['01-03-19','FORTAP-MUMBAI/',np.NaN, np.NaN, '49656.25Cr',0],
    ['01-03-19','FORTAP-MUMBAI/******',np.NaN,6000.00,'55656.25Cr',1],
    [np.NaN,'UP/*ABC*/*DEF*','UPI/*PQR*/*XYZ*','paytm/NA',np.NaN,1],
['01-03-19','MBK/*ABCDEF*/*ZZZ*',289.00,np.NaN,'55357.25Cr',3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
print (df)
df['merged'] = df[['Description','Debit','Credit']].apply(lambda x: ''.join([str(a) for a in x if pd.notnull(a) and not isinstance(a, float)]) ,axis=1)
df['Description'] = df.groupby("originalIdx")['merged'].transform(lambda x: "".join(x))
df.dropna(subset=['Date'],inplace=True)
df.drop(columns='merged',inplace=True)
print (df)
```

Before and after output attached:

Before:

```
       Date           Description            Debit    Credit     Balance  originalIdx  
0  01-03-19        FORTAP-MUMBAI/              NaN       NaN  49656.25Cr             0  
1  01-03-19  FORTAP-MUMBAI/******              NaN    6000.0  55656.25Cr             1  
2       NaN        UP/*ABC*/*DEF*  UPI/*PQR*/*XYZ*  paytm/NA         NaN             1  
3  01-03-19    MBK/*ABCDEF*/*ZZZ*            289.0       NaN  55357.25Cr             3
```

After:

```
       Date                                                Description  Debit  Credit     Balance  originalIdx  
0  01-03-19                                             FORTAP-MUMBAI/    NaN     NaN   49656.25Cr           0  
1  01-03-19  FORTAP-MUMBAI/******UP/*ABC*/*DEF*UPI/*PQR*/*XYZ*paytm/NA    NaN  6000.0   55656.25Cr           1  
3  01-03-19                                         MBK/*ABCDEF*/*ZZZ*  289.0     NaN   55357.25Cr           3
```

Comment: Description value show the blank value  ..not working

Comment: can you share the sample data that created the blank value please?

Comment: I am unable to  upload image or df in comment

Comment: Ok. What are the values in the row that created the error. Can you share that?

Comment: I update the output which i can get from your code please check

Comment: I would have preferred that you updated the question section. Anyway, I have included your input data. If this is the input data, the code should work. Let me see what's not working.

Comment: No my input data is , look like which i can above mention in Question

Comment: updated the code and posted. See new solution if it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using pandas!

```
df.fillna("").groupby("originalIdx").agg(lambda x: "".join(x))
```

You can do it easily with this line.

We group the column, and with agg we execute the lambda function that we concatenate the output

EDIT:

To control the data None we use `.fillna ("").` we replace the None by empty string